# Determining dev name when lsblk doesn't work

Tags: printing

My goal is to update the firmware on a color laser printer. The documentation states:

> For Unix systems:
>   Any method that delivers the `.RFU` file to the printer will work, including:
>   `$ cp /home/yourmachine/FILENAME /dev/XXXX`
>   where `XXXX` is the appropriate parallel device; and where `/home/yourmachine/FILENAME` contains the `.RFU` file.

If the printer is connected via USB, how would I go about determining XXXX? I've tried `lsblk`, but that doesn't tell me anything useful beyond what I already know:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 234.6G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   3.9G  0 part [SWAP]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you look in /dev/ to see if you could identify the printer?  lsblk is only for block devices (storage)

Comment: What does the command `sudo lpstat -s` return?

Comment: @Terrance, `device for HP-Color-LaserJet-3800: hp:/usb/HP_Color_LaserJet_3800?serial=CNYBB06996`

Comment: @ravery, I'm just guessing here, but maybe `/dev/usb/hiddev0` is it?